# Write not equal to "!=" in array of WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: php, arrays, where-clause

I have two conditions for my where clause and I am writing it inside an array. Following is my code so far:

```
public function getRelatedNews($id, $news_id) {

    $args = array(
        'fields' => array(
            'news.id', 
            'news.title',  
            'news.story', 
            'news.image',
            'news.status',
            'news.added_date',
            'categories.title AS news_category',
            '(SELECT users.full_name FROM users WHERE id = news.added_by) as author',
            ),
        'where' => array(
            'news_category' => $id
            'news.id'    !=> $news_id 
        ),
        'join'  => 'LEFT JOIN categories on news.news_category = categories.id',
        'limit' => array(0, 2)
    );
    return $this->select($args);
}
```

As I am writing condition inside array I am using `=>` for equal but for the second condition I am not being able to use `!=>`. What should I use for not equal conditions if they are inside array like the above?

I have `SELECT` query like this:

```
final protected function select($args = array(), $is_die = false){
        try {

        $this->sql = "SELECT ";
        if (isset($args['fields'])) {
            if (is_array($args['fields'])) {
                $this->sql .= implode(', ', $args['fields']);
            } else {
                $this->sql .= $args['fields'];
            }
        } else {
            $this->sql .= " * ";
        }
        $this->sql .= " FROM ";
        if (!isset($this->table) || empty($this->table)) {
            throw new Exception("Table not set");
        }
        $this->sql .= $this->table;

        /*Join Query*/
        if (isset($args['join']) && !empty($args['join'])) {
            $this->sql .= " ".$args['join'];
        }
        /*Join Query*/

        if (isset($args['where']) && !empty($args['where'])) {
            if (is_array($args['where'])) {
                $temp = array();
                foreach ($args['where'] as $column_name => $value) {
                    $str = $column_name." = :".$column_name;
                    $temp[] = $str;
                }
                $this->sql .= " WHERE ".implode(' AND ', $temp);
            } else {
                $this->sql .= " WHERE ".$args['where'];
            }
        }

        /*Group*/
        if (isset($args['group_by']) && !empty($args['group_by'])) {
            $this->sql .= " GROUP BY ".$args['group_by'];
        }
        /*Group*/

        /*Order*/
        if (isset($args['order_by']) && !empty($args['order_by'])) {
            $this->sql .= " ORDER BY ".$args['order_by'];
        } else {
            $this->sql .= " ORDER BY ".$this->table.".id DESC";
        }
        /*Order*/

        /*Limit*/
        if (isset($args['limit']) && !empty($args['limit'])) {
            if (is_array($args['limit'])) {
                $this->sql .= " LIMIT ".$args['limit'][0].",".$args['limit'][1];
            } else {
                $this->sql .= " LIMIT ".$args['limit'];
            }
        }
        /*Limit*/
        $this->stmt = $this->conn->prepare($this->sql);
        if (isset($args['where']) && !empty($args['where']) && is_array($args['where'])) {
            foreach ($args['where'] as $column_name => $value) {
                if (is_int($value)) {
                    $param = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                } elseif (is_bool($value)) {
                    $param = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                } elseif (is_null($value)) {
                    $param = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                } else {
                    $param = PDO::PARAM_STR;
                }
                if ($param) {
                    $this->stmt->bindValue(":".$column_name, $value, $param);
                }
            }
        }
        if ($is_die) {

            echo $this->sql;
            debugger($this->stmt);

        }
        $this->stmt->execute();

        $data = $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        return $data;

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
                error_log(
                    date('Y-m-d h:i:s A').", Select Query: ".$e->getMessage()."\r\n"
                    , 3, ERROR_PATH.'/error.log');
                return false;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                error_log(
                    date('Y-m-d h:i:s A').", General: ".$e->getMessage()."\r\n"
                    , 3, ERROR_PATH.'/error.log');
                return false;
            }
    }
```

Comment: You would need to divide your value into a subarray e.g. `'news.id' => [ 'value' => $news_id, 'operator' => '!=',],`

Comment: php framework ?

Comment: set 'news.id <>' => $news_id

Comment: How does `$this->select()` look like?

Comment: @Abutouq 'news.id <>' => $news_id didn't work.

Comment: @DarkBee can you answer it?

Comment: @michalhosna I have that code in OOP, its just select function.

Comment: @Alisha and can you like post the function here? You question is unanswerable properly if we don't know what the function expects.

Comment: You'll need to show the `select()` method, at the very least.

Comment: @michalhosna I have updated my question.

Comment: @Qirel I have updated my question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reflect on my comment, change your data structure to this:

```
public function getRelatedNews($id, $news_id) {
    $args = array(
        'fields' => array(
            'news.id', 
            'news.title',  
            'news.story', 
            'news.image',
            'news.status',
            'news.added_date',
            'categories.title AS news_category',
            '(SELECT users.full_name FROM users WHERE id = news.added_by) as author',
        ),
        'where' => array(
            'news_category' => $id
            'news.id'       => array('value' => $news_id, 'operator' => '!=', ), 
        ),
        'join'  => 'LEFT JOIN categories on news.news_category = categories.id',
        'limit' => array(0, 2)
    );
    return $this->select($args);
}
```

Now you still have to change your `select` method, based on the new data.

```
foreach ($args['where'] as $column_name => $data) {
    /**
        Transform to array when only value is passed
        Use default operator = when this is the case
    **/
    if (!is_array($data)) {
        $data = array(
            'value'     => $data,
            'operator'  => '=',
        );
    }
    $str = $column_name.' '.$data['operator'].' :'.str_replace('.', '_', $column_name);
    $temp[] = $str;
}
```

And change the value bindings:

```
foreach ($args['where'] as $column_name => $data) {
    $value = is_array($data) ? $data['value'] : $data; //check if passed where statement was an array, fetch value if so
    if (is_int($value)) {
        $param = PDO::PARAM_INT;
    }elseif (is_bool($value)) {
        $param = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
    }elseif (is_null($value)) {
        $param = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
    }else {
        $param = PDO::PARAM_STR;
    }
    if ($param) {
        $this->stmt->bindValue(":".str_replace('.', '_', $column_name), $value, $param);
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't that effect my previous fuctions written for `SELECT` query?

Comment: No because the code will transform every passed value to the `where` into an array if not, with `=` as operator

Comment: that didn't help and also that affect my previous code written for `SELECT` query.

Comment: First of all, if I use the code provided by you, I am not being able to get inside the admin because I have used `SELECT` query and Secondly, I am getting this `SQL` after using code `SELECT news.id, news.title, news.story, news.image, news.status, news.added_date, categories.title AS news_category, (SELECT users.full_name FROM users WHERE id = news.added_by) as author FROM news LEFT JOIN categories on news.news_category = categories.id WHERE news_category = :news_category AND news.id = :news.id ORDER BY news.id DESC LIMIT 0,2` and as you can see the query says `news.id = :news.id`

Comment: Then you are doing something, see the demo i've posted with the output `SELECT news.id, news.title FROM news WHERE news.title = :news.title AND news.id != :news.id`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188346/discussion-between-alisha-and-darkbee).

Answer (score -1):

You need to use your cide like that

```
public function getRelatedNews($id, $news_id) {

    $args = array(
        'fields' => array(
            'news.id', 
            'news.title',  
            'news.story', 
            'news.image',
            'news.status',
            'news.added_date',
            'categories.title AS news_category',
            '(SELECT users.full_name FROM users WHERE id = news.added_by) as author',
            ),
        'where' => array(
            'news_category' => $id
            'news.id !=' => $news_id 
        ),
        'join'  => 'LEFT JOIN categories on news.news_category = categories.id',
        'limit' => array(0, 2)
    );
    return $this->select($args);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You have !=> currently if you want no  equals to it should be !=

Comment: We cannot use `!=` inside array.